# Acrobat Preflight - Checking Object/Line Width

Tags: print-production, adobe-acrobat

It's been years since I've used Pre-flight in Acrobat, but I've had a situation come up where I need to check certain objects before PDFs go to print.

Our packaging files are created in Illustrator and then fonts are converted to outlines. Even if the font size is above minimum recommended by the print shop, some parts of the font may be too narrow. See image, where the bowl of the u meets the stem. This area was smaller than 0.3pt in width. (Keep in mind this is text converted to outlines).[image]

How can I check something like this in Acrobat Pre-flight? Is there a profile in Acrobat which checks for this? The Pre-flight in Acrobat is so powerful I'm a bit overwhelmed searching for this.

Thanks in advance! Angus

Edit: Theoretically I could preflight before I convert to outlines if that would make the solution simpler.

Comment: A first question is whether you really, really must convert your font to outlines. Can't your print shop deal with PDF properly, not even a PDF/X-1a?

Comment: I know, normally I never do, but these are the requirements for this customer. Regardless of whether they're outlines or not I still have the problem of how to spot areas/lines/objects/parts of text, which are too thin ...